# Old printed object deformed over time

Tags: resin, elegoo-mars

I have an Elegoo Mars.

I have printed a figure in Resin, but after some months I found this - the figure is as if it is not completely cured. The base is open (see picture below). it wasn't open before!

It was printed a month ago, I am not precisely sure. I think I only machine cured and sunlight.

How is this possible?

[image: Base of 3D print]

Comment: How long did you cure it, and what was the layer time? You might have too short a layer time, the core possibly being all *goo* but not solid...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are cracks as a result of overstressing due internal stresses to further curing of the print over the course of time (stress cracks).

Most probably the print wasn't cured properly or slicing wasn't optimal.

Comment: The outside layer are perfect! So I think the problem can be slicing!

Answer (score 1):

You should probably cure more, but curing should not be complete during print, or the layer will not stick properly.

Also, when you cure with UV light or the sun after the print is completed, you can cure only up to a certain depth, [likely around a couple of millimetres](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/13660/can-uv-cure-inside-opaque-or-more-massive-printed-object).

If your object was massive and you didn't "hollow it" then some resin got trapped inside it and it didn't cure properly initially. It may slowly cure later, but by the time the object cracks due to stress, some resin may still be liquid enough to cause the issue.